# How to reference to two different collection for one field in MongoDB/Mongoose?

Tags: mongodb, mean-stack, mongoose-schema

I'm setting up username model schema with username field which is to be referred to user model schema and organization model schema. The aim is to store organization and user's username in one collection. I have made the following code but it's giving run time error.

```
const UsernameSchema = new Schema ({
  username: {type: Schema.Types.String, ref: 'User', 'Organization' }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Only the object Ids can be referred. If you wanna store the username in one collection then you can only store it as a string and so use find query in order to get the respective data. You can also index the username attribute to make your query faster. If not ref, then you use $lookup in aggregation.